# Ajax response return undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pusher

Hi I have been using ajax for many times. But I can't figure out whats the problem with my code this time. My head is blowing up since 2 days. I am using pusher for the realtime notification in CodeIgniter. Here's my code.

```
  $(document).on("click", ".myonoffswitch", function () {
    if (confirm("Sure!!! You want to Change the post status?"))
    {
        var thiss = $(this);
        var prod_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var status = $(this).attr('value');
        var tdid = $(this).parent().prev().attr('class');
        var td = $(this).parent().prev();

        var adsstatus = $.ajax({type: "POST", dataType: "json", url: base_url + 'init/ads_status', data: {'prod_id': prod_id, 'status': status}});
        $.when(adsstatus).done(function (adsstatuss) {
            var msg;
            msg = adsstatuss;
            alert(msg.length);
            var updated_status = msg[0].post_status;
            alert(updated_status);
            //alert(updated_status);
            if (updated_status == "0" && tdid == prod_id) {
                td.css("background", "#ccffcc");
                td.text("On");
                thiss.val(updated_status);


            }
            if (updated_status == "1" && tdid == prod_id) {
                td.css("background", "#ffcccc");
                td.text("Off");
                thiss.val(updated_status);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

### ads_status (method in CodeIgniter)

```
 public function ads_status() {
    $prod_id = $_POST['prod_id'];
    $status = $_POST['status'];
    if ($status == "1") {
        $new_status = "0";
        $this->cmsdbmodel->ads_status($prod_id, $new_status);
        $dat = $this->cmsdbmodel->get_updated_status($prod_id);
        $ads_type = "product";
        $emailreturn = $this->send_email_ads_status($prod_id, $ads_type);


        //send user alert of product//
        if ($dat[0]->post_status == "0") {
            $lastInsertedId = $prod_id;
            $modelNBrandId = $this->dbmodel->checkProductContainsAlert($lastInsertedId);
            $getAlertEmail = $this->dbmodel->getAlertEmailFromBrandNModelId($modelNBrandId);
            if (!empty($getAlertEmail)) {
                foreach ($getAlertEmail as $alerts) {
                    $alertsEmail = $alerts->email;
                }
            }
            $alertsPost = $this->dbmodel->getPostAlerts($lastInsertedId);
            $sendPostAlerts = json_encode($alertsPost);
            $encrytpEmail = hash('sha256', $alertsEmail);
            $this->pusher->trigger($encrytpEmail, 'alerts', $sendPostAlerts);
        }
        //send user alert of product//

        $realtime = $this->realTime_charts();
        $realtime["post_status"] = $dat[0]->post_status;
        $realtime["emailres"] = $emailreturn;
        $data = $realtime;
        $this->pusher->trigger('recent_activity', 'new_event1', $data);
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
 }
```

Here I want to trigger event in pusher as well as echo json object. But in ajax, response is `undefined`. Also in console I can see json but when alerting the reponse it says `undefined`. Wheres problem in my code. Please help me.

Comment: Try using console.log instead of alert :) That will help already.

Comment: Did you look at the Ajax response in the console. What did it return back?